# CNTK 2.5.1 Function::Load spills unhandled exception 'Module Not Found'

Tags: cntk

I encountered an unhandled exception, **Module Not Found**, when I load a model that can be loaded with CNTK 2.3(C++ API). I tried to load 'test.dnn' from Function::Load function then it spilled above exception that is unhandled though.

I can't find any hint about it.